# What is the benefit of using Azure SQL elastic queries vs handling the cross DB queries in my .Net code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, azure

I have Azure SQL database database1 in server Server1.database.windows.net
I need to retrieve some records from this database, and insert them in a table in different database on different Azure server.
Do you think for this scenario it's better to do it using .Net or to use Elastic queries?
Also, is there any limitations for the elastic queries?

Comment: Well in theory (I've never used it), you could store your elastic query in the database as a stored procedure. So you don't have a seperate codebase.  Also the data would be doing one trip from the remote database to the local database. If you ran compiled .net code on a different server the data would be making two trips.

Answer (score 0):

> I have Azure SQL database database1 in server Server1.database.windows.net I need to retrieve some records from this database, and insert them in a table in different database on different Azure server. Do you think for this scenario it's better to do it using .Net or to use Elastic queries?

Your requirement is query data from one database and then insert returned data into another (different) database, in my opinion, making these operations via code in your program would completely meet your requirement, elastic query is not required for your scenario. Normally the goal of using elastic query is to facilitate querying scenarios where multiple databases contribute rows into a single overall result. You can find detailed information of the elastic query feature in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview).

Besides, [sp_execute_remote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-remote-azure-sql-database) can help us execute remote stored procedure calls or remote functions, which could be another approach for your scenario.

> is there any limitations for the elastic queries?

Under "Preview limitations" section in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview#preview-limitations), you can see:

- Running your first elastic query can take up to a few minutes on the Standard performance tier. This time is necessary to load the elastic query functionality; loading performance improves with higher performance tiers.
- Scripting of external data sources or external tables from SSMS or SSDT is not yet supported.
- Import/Export for SQL DB does not yet support external data sources and external tables. If you need to use Import/Export, drop these objects before exporting and then re-create them after importing.
- Elastic query currently only supports read-only access to external tables. You can, however, use full T-SQL functionality on the database where the external table is defined. This can be useful to, e.g., persist temporary results using, e.g., SELECT INTO , or to define stored procedures on the elastic query database which refer to external tables.
- Except for nvarchar(max), LOB types are not supported in external table definitions. As a workaround, you can create a view on the remote database that casts the LOB type into nvarchar(max), define your external table over the view instead of the base table and then cast it back into the original LOB type in your queries.
- Column statistics over external tables are currently not supported. Tables statistics are supported, but need to be created manually.